# Importing MathView zip file to android studio using kotlin

Tags: java, windows, kotlin, android-studio, import

I have problems on how to import the MathView into my application. I don't know which file is to import. I am relatively new to app development. I am currently building an application as a project study. It is similar to a calculator. TextView can't show math equations and I've stumbled upon this method wherein to import a UI which is called MathView. Can you please help me in detail how to import, stuff like "implementations" and etc. It would be a great help. I hope you could help me like step by step tutorial on how to do this. Thank you

detailed instruction regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using Android Studio you can open your build.gradle file and add the dependency and re-sync the project

```
implementation 'io.github.kexanie:MathView:0.5.0'
```

You need to add MathView to your XML layout file and also define which redering engine to use.

```
<io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
    android:id="@+id/mathView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:engine="markdown" />
```

There are several rendering engines you can use such as MathJax, Markdown and JSoup. Here we have just used Markdown.

To initialize MathView library add the following inside your onCreate funtion

```
MathView mathView = findViewById(R.id.mathView);

        String mathString = "f(x) = a * x^4 + b + c";
        mathView.setText(mathString);
```

Now any equations you have that have been set to the text of MathView will be rendered with rendering engine that you set in the XML file when you run your application. Your text will now be displayed as equations.

Comment: do i need to import something from github?

Comment: io.github.kexanie: is the Maven group ID. So the group 'kexanie' maintains this 3rd party library which is hosted on GitHub